# Is there a ulock mount that uses the bottle cage openings?

Tags: carbon, lock

I found one that a guy made I think with 3d printers or something but seems like an excellent solution.
[image]

I have a carbon frame bike and I don't want to use traditional ulock mount at the top because it creates a stress point by compressing. And the bottom section of this bike is too thick for the holder.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but that's a great idea.  Downsides are that your lock is a lot heavier than a pump and water bottle,   So the mount might need more thickness/meat, which means longer bolts.  The weight could be more manageable if you were prepared to forgo a water bottle in that position too, to keep the lock on the centerline.

Comment: On a steel frame yes, but I have serious doubts with a carbon frame. The stress on the bolts may tear them out since the wall thickness is probably not meant to withstand the weight and the vibration from road-use.

Comment: @carel - A water bottle mount is intended to hold a 800 ml bottle of water, so 800 grammes and some people mount pumps/inflaters there too.  So assume 1 kilogram.  But these locks weigh somewhat more than that.  Nolawi, how heavy is your lock?

Comment: @Criggie: The weight and the CG of the bottle are closer to the frame so there is less leverage.

Comment: It ways about 2.2 lbs

Comment: You could clip it to your handlebar -- kryptonite makes a handlebar mount for some locks. Dunno if its carbon ready though (if you have a carbon bar).

Comment: 2.2 lbs is about 1 kg, so the weight is ordinally similar.   Go for it.  I once made an ebike with three SLA batteries on the water bottle rack, that was ~12 kg, although it also had some stabilisers to the top tube and seat tube.   Consider a safety strap so if the mount does snap the lock doesn't fall clean off.

Comment: i think i am saying where can I get one like this.... and how come its not been a solution in then industry

Comment: I remember being quite unpleased with the mount that came with my lock.  While attempting to place it as in your picture, I noticed that I didn't have enough space for my water/pump.  I want the product in your picture, but if I were to guess why it's not standard, I would say it's because the space issue.  We all have different sized bikes and different sized locks.

Comment: There are folding locks, similar to a carpenter's folding ruler, with brackets that fit where a bottle cage would fit. These have a lot of joints, so a lot of potential weak spots, although most locks have some weak spot (and it only takes one).

Comment: I have a folding lock that fits in the bottle cage mount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a ulock, but it's the same idea.

[image]

It's a 0.9 lb bike lock made from Titanium. They cost $99 and come with a water bottle cage mount as shown.

TiGr® mini Bike Lock
[enter link description here](https://tigrlock.com/mini/#!)

[image]

Comment: FYI This particular lock has been proven to not live up to the promises, it can most certainly be cut easily with boltcutters.